# Why is there a fold method for Form in Play 2.0.2?

Tags: api, scala, playframework

I'm referring to this:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form

If you search for a method called fold, it shows a method used for handling the form. Is there a reason why this method is called fold? Given that fold already has a meaning for list like objects, it seems that this name could easily cause confusion.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8539935/334519) and the answers for a discussion of `fold` across apparently very different types.

Comment: I did consider that, yes, however the behvior of fold here is rather different - it acts more like a map, rather than a fold.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `fold` on `Form` is pretty close to the `fold` on the `Either` class in the Scala standard library, which is similarly often used to capture the outcome of a process that could either succeed (in which case you have a `Right` containing the result) or fail (in which case you have a `Left` containing an error, or maybe leftover input, etc.). So I'll use `Either` as an example here. Just picture `Form[T]` as a kind of `Either[Form[T], T]` if necessary.

### Fold on collections

We can (very informally) imagine lists as having lots of different "shapes" (empty lists, lists of length one, length two, etc.), and `fold` (or `foldLeft`, in the following example) as a method that collapses any list of the proper type to a single kind of thing, no matter what its shape is:

```
scala> def catInts(xs: List[Int]): String = xs.foldLeft("")(_ + _.toString)
catInts: (xs: List[Int])String

scala> catInts(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
res0: String = 1234

scala> catInts(Nil)
res1: String = ""
```

### Fold on Either / Form

Similarly we can imagine `Either` as having two shapes (`Right` and `Left`), and its `fold` as a method that takes an `Either` of either shape and returns a single kind of thing. Say we have the following method for parsing strings as integers and returning an `Either`:

```
def parseInt(s: String): Either[String, Int] =
  try Right(s.toInt) catch {
    case _: NumberFormatException => Left(s)
  }
```

And the following method that uses `fold` to collapse the `Either`:

```
def toDefault(e: Either[String, Int]): Int = e.fold(_ => 42, identity)
```

Which we can use like this:

```
scala> toDefault(parseInt("AAARGH!!"))
res2: Int = 42

scala> toDefault(parseInt("123"))
res3: Int = 123
```

This is all obviously very impressionistic and hand-wavy, but it might help give a more intuitive sense of how the different `fold` methods are fundamentally the same kind of thing. You can see [the question I linked in a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8539935/334519) or [the Wikipedia entry on catamorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism) for more detail.

Answer (score -2):

This is the explanation of {play for scala}:  In Scala, fold is often used as the name of a method that collapses (or folds) multiple pos- sible values into a single value. In this case, we’re attempting to fold either a form with validation errors or one that validates correctly into a response.