# Scala: accessing common subtype of Either

Tags: scala

Both CSplit and MapCanvT are subtypes of Scala Swing Component. So type CanvNode is always a subtype of Component. I haven't got to grips with the functional stuff of Scala collections yet like fold. Is there any way to reduce this code (aside from putting the match in a function) and get rid of those matches?

```
type CanvNode = Either[CSplit, MapCanvT]   

class CSplit(var s1: CanvNode, var s2: CanvNode) extends SplitPane
{         
  topComponent =  s1 match { case Left (s) => s; case Right (s) => s} 
  bottomComponent = s2 match { case Left (s) => s; case Right (s) => s}
```

The above compiles. Ideally I'd just write:

```
type CanvNode = Either[CSplit, MapCanvT]   

class CSplit(var s1: CanvNode, var s2: CanvNode) extends SplitPane
{         
  topComponent =  s1
  bottomComponent = s2
```

but that won't compile.

Comment: It seems like the static types of both `topComponent` and `bottomComponent` will be `CanvNode`, since you can't tell at compile time what the value of the match expression produces.  Can you give a little more information about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ConnorDoyle Edited for clarity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fold` will in fact do what you want here. You can rewrite this:

```
topComponent = s1 match { case Left (s) => s; case Right (s) => s}
```

As this:

```
topComponent = s1.fold(identity, identity)
```

And the inferred type will be the least upper bound of `CSplit` and `MapCanvT`.

`Either` also provides a slightly more compact way to write this:

```
topComponent = s1.merge
```

Through an implicit conversion to a [`MergeableEither`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Either$$MergeableEither.html).

Comment: Thanks, I thought surely there must be something simpler.

Comment: You can also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11269221/334519) for example for more information about `fold` on `Either`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not model this differently as a trait?

```
sealed trait CanvNode
class MapCanvT extends Component with CanvNode
class CSplit extends SplitPane with CanvNode(var s1: CanvNode,
                                             var s2: CanvNode) {
    topComponent = s1
    bottomCompoenent = s2
}
```

Comment: Because MapCanvT can't inherit from CanvNode as its implementations are defined independently of this class. Possibly it could be made into a type class of CanvNode but I think that would be just as complicated as using scala.Either.