# Elegant ways to extract element values from Either[String,Option[NodeSeq]]

Tags: xml, scala, refactoring

Lets say I am given an XML as follows:

```
<a><b><c>hello</c><d>world</d><e>again</e></b></a>
```

I am given a function: getXmlStream which has the following signature:

```
def getXmlStream(xmlPath:String):Either[String,Option[NodeSeq]]
```

When I call getXmlStream with a path passed in it, I would get the Either with the Left being the error and the right an Option[NodeSeq].

Now, if the NodeSeq is not None, I would need to get the values of elements  and , which would be "hello" and "world" respectively.

My attempt to get the elements out is as follows:

```
val elems = (getXmlStream(xmlFilePath)) match {
               case Left(error:String) => None
               case Right(xmlStreamOpt) => {
                 xmlStreamOpt map {
                  (r \\ "c" text, r \\ "d" text)
                 } 
               }  
            }).getOrElse("","")
```

The `elems` will now consist of a tuple that has the values `("hello","world")` if they are there other wise it will be a tuple of empty strings.

I don't think that the snippet I have written above is idiomatic scala. Can somebody suggest how I could refactor it.

The second issue I feel is that I am hardcoding the Nodes "c" and "d" in the snippet. If now, the requirement comes in to extract "e", would I be modifying the expression `(r \\ "c" text, r \\ "d" text)` to `(r \\ "c" text, r \\ "d" text, r \\ "e" text)`? Is it possible to make the xml element extraction more dynamic?

Comment: what about using a Scalaz Validation? It's a nice enhancement to Either

Comment: @Edmondo1984 - Thanks. I am not familiar with Scalaz validation. It will be great if you could provide an example of how it could be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner that is I think still pretty clear:

```
res.right.toOption.flatten.fold(("", ""))(r => (r \\ "c" text, r \\ "d" text))
```

We can step through what's going on here: first we take the right projection of the `Either` and turn it into an `Option` by mapping `Left` to `None`. Now we have a nested `Option`, which we can flatten to get an `Option[NodeSeq]`. Then we fold over the possible shapes of the `Option` (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265352/why-is-there-a-fold-method-for-form-in-play-2-0-2) and the links there for more discussion).

Note that `fold` only showed up on `Option` in 2.10. If you're working with a version of Scala earlier than that, the following is exactly equivalent:

```
res.right.toOption.flatten.map(
  r => (r \\ "c" text, r \\ "d" text)
).getOrElse(("", ""))
```

The standard library doesn't provide much in the way of working with tuples in the fashion you describe in your last paragraph, but there are libraries such as [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) and [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) that do. For example, with Scalaz's `Bifunctor`, you can write your current version like this:

```
res.right.toOption.flatten.fold(("", ""))(r => ("c", "d").umap(r \\ _ text))
```

And Shapeless would allow you to add elements to the tuple more easily (but that's a little more complex and probably best addressed in a new question).

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
scala> getXmlStream(path) match {
     |   case Right(Some(xml)) => (xml\\"c" text, xml\\"d" text)
     |   case _ => ("", "")
     | }
```