# In what way is Scala's Option fold a catamorphism?

Tags: scala, category-theory, scala-option, catamorphism, recursion-schemes

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328007/why-doesnt-option-have-a-fold-method) question suggests that the fold method on Option in Scala is a catamoprhism. From the wikipedia a [catamophism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism) is "the unique homomorphism from an initial algebra into some other algebra. The concept has been applied to functional programming as folds". So that seems fair, but leads me to an [initial algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_algebra) as the initial object in the category of [F-algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-algebra).

So if the fold on Option is really a catamophism there needs to be some functor F, to create the category of F-algebras where Option would be the initial object. I can't figure out what this functor would be.

For Lists of type `A` the functor `F` is `F[X] = 1 + A * X`. This makes sense because List is a recursive data type, so if `X` is `List[A]` then the above reads that a list of type `A` is either the empty list (`1`), or (`+`) a pair (`*`) of an `A` and a `List[A]`. But Option isn't recursive. `Option[A]` would just be `1 + A` (Nothing or an `A`). So I don't see where the functor is.

Just to be clear I realize that Option is already a functor, in that it takes `A` to `Option[A]`, but what is done for lists is different, the `A` is fixed and the functor is used to describe how to recursively construct the data type.

On a related note, if it is not a catamorphism it probably shouldn't be called a fold, as that leads to some [confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539935/whats-the-relation-of-fold-on-option-either-etc-and-fold-on-traversable).

Comment: What's the basis for your assumption that `F` _has_ to be recursive? Lots of algebraic data types aren't. In any case you could always "cheat" and write something like `F[X] = 1 + Const A X`.

Comment: Is `F[X] = 1 + Const A X` the same as the functor as `F[X] = 1 + A`? (The functor that sends every type to Option[A].) I suppose that works, but it is so trivial that I assumed there would be more going on.

Under this F, any F-algebra is just a type B with a map from Option[A] to B. An then the initialness just says given a type B and a map from Option[A] to B, there exists a unique map from Option[A] to B.

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/free-rectypes/free-rectypes.txt (linked from the wikipedia) also implies the point of initial F-algebras is for recursive data types.

Comment: Furthermore, If you allow constant Functors, then for any type `T`, you can consider the functor `F[X] = T`. Then an F-algebra is simply a type `B` together with a map `g` from `T` to `B`. `T` is immediately the initial algebra, and the catamoprhism is simply applying `g` to objects of type `T`. Which seems to be what is happening, since Option[A] is a coproduct of `A` and `Nothing`, and map from `Option[A]` to `B` splits into a map from `A` to `B` and a map from `Nothing` to B, which fits with the type signature of `fold` on `Option`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the comments are in the right track. I'm just a beginner so I probably have some misconceptions. Yes, the whole point is to be able to model recursive types, but I think nothing precludes a "non-recursive" F-algebra. Since the initial algebra is the "least fixed point" solution to the equation X ~= F X. In the case of Option, the solution is trivial, as there's no recursion involved :)

Other examples of initial algebras:

List[X] = 1 + A * X to represent list = Nil | Cons a list

Tree[X] = A + A * X * X to represent tree = Leaf a | Node a tree tree

In the same way:

Option[X] = 1 + A to represent option = None | Some a

The justification for the existence of a "constant" functor is pretty easy, how do you represent a tree's node? 
In fact, to algebraically model (simple) recursive datatypes you need only the following functors:

- U (Unit, represents empty)
- K (Constant, captures a value)
- I (Identity, represent the recursive position)
- * (product)
- + (coproduct)

A good reference I found is [Functional Generic Programming](http://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/cursos/proggen/Papers/FGP.pdf.gz)

Shameless plug: I'm playing with those concepts in code in [scala-reggen](https://github.com/gclaramunt/scala-reggen)